# Rounding Off For a Cell

Tags: java, rounding

Using the following code i am trying to round off a double value to its nearest whole number Eg 2.3 to 2.0 ,2.6 to 3.0.But if i pass value like 2.5  as per Math.round function it should return 3 but i am getting an output of 2

```
private static void addData(Table b) throws Exception
{
    Font font = new Font(Color.BLACK);
    Cell cell = null;
    double value = 143.567;

    cell = new Cell(new Phrase(roundoffValue(value), font));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(cell);    
}

public static String roundoffValue(double value )
{
   return String.valueOf( new Float( Math.round(value)));
}
```

Comment: You may be doing something else as well, could you post your actual `roundoffValue`, because, you are calling `roundoffValue` with two parameters and what you have posted is having just one parameter. Either you are looking at wrong method (overloaded) or there is something else in the body of the method.

Comment: Note that you must be careful when dealing with `double` or `float` and such corner cases like rounding up or down at `.5`. These values internally can often not precisely represent an exact value, only up to some limit. So it could be possible, depending on where you get those values, that it is slightly below `.5` by `0.00...01` or so and thus getting rounded down instead of up. That is especially the case for such values after some exhaustive computations on them.

Comment: Your question is unrelated to iText so I deleted the tag.

Comment: Zabuza has a good point. If you care about precision, do not use floating point numbers. [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is probably the class you should be using.

Comment: Just as a demonstration: `((0.01 + 1) * 2 - 2) / 2` should evaluate to `0.01` again but it actually is `0.010000000000000009` in Java. That is because they loose precision during computation.

Comment: I don't see how 143.567 is related to the issue with 2.5. Can you provide an actual [mcve]?

Comment: @Zabuza that's not it, 2.5 decimal is exactly 10.1 in binary notation. Any decimal value that is a base-2 fraction (0.5 = 1/2, 0.25 = 1/2^2, 0.625 = 5/2^3) can be represented as a binary number without rounding errors. The web has many ieee conversion tools that clearly show this. So something else is going on. Also the OP has posted incorrect code. Their method signature is different.

Comment: The OP is edited. Incorrect signature was just a typo. @AmedeeVanGasse

Comment: Also note the difference between `2.5` and `2.5d`. The OP should make this explicit.

Comment: I don't see how the iText code around it is related to the issue with 2.5. Can you provide an actual [mcve]?

Comment: Question flagged as unclear.

Comment: Why not `new Phrase(String.format("%f", value), font)` and get rid of the `roundoffValue` method? That method is so trivial that it only makes sense if you get paid for lines of code. Using `String.format` has the additional benefits that you very clearly see that you are using the `(String, Font)` constructor of `Phrase`. `roundoffValue(value)` is bad code because A it does not reveal intent B it has multiple responsibilities (rounding AND converting to string) and C why two times the word value in succession?

Answer (score 0):

[`Math#round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) does round 2.5 up to 3.  The docs state:

> Returns the closest {@code long} to the argument, with ties
>   rounding to positive infinity.

```
// Prints 3.
System.out.println(String.valueOf(Math.round(2.5d)));

// Prints 144.
System.out.println(String.valueOf(Math.round(143.567)));
```

Comment: Sorry i was using  return String.valueOf( new Float( Math.round(vsi)));

Comment: @GaneshKaruppaiha Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: As @shmosel says, makes no difference. When converting from a `double` result to a `Float` you definitely use some precision but that does not change a `3` to a `2`. The "*problem*" did already happen before converting to `Float`.